# Grouping when using geom_line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, linegraph

[image]

I am receiving this error - Error in check_aesthetics(): ## ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x and y in my code when I run R markdown.

Here is my code

```
{r, fig.show='hide'}
ggplot(data=hourlyIntensities_data) +
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = ActivityHour, y = AverageIntensity, group = 1)) +
geom_line(mapping = aes(x = ActivityHour, y = AverageIntensity, group = 1)) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) + 
scale_x_discrete(limits = axisorder) +
ggtitle("Average Intensity user_6",
      subtitle = "4-12-2016")
```

here is my dput

```
structure(list(Id = c("user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
"user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
"user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
"user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6"), 
ActivityHour = c("12:00 AM", "1:00 AM", "2:00 AM", "3:00 AM", 
"4:00 AM", "5:00 AM", "6:00 AM", "7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "9:00 AM", 
"10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", 
"3:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM", 
"9:00 PM", "10:00 PM", "11:00 PM"), TotalIntensity = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 13L, 13L, 143L, 20L, 11L, 19L, 
54L, 9L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AverageIntensity = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.466667, 0.216667, 0.216667, 2.383333, 
0.333333, 0.183333, 0.316667, 0.9, 0.15, 0.316667, 0.4, 0.316667, 
0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

dput axis order

```
c("7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "9:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 AM", 
"1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM", 
"7:00 PM", "8:00 PM")
```

when I remove group = 1 I no longer receive the error when printing HOWEVER I do not get a line to print on my graph.

Comment: Is `axisorder` a vector? Yes could you provide?

Comment: I dont get this error when I comment out the `scale_x_discrete()` line (commented out since we currently do not have the values for `axisorder`)

Comment: @TarJae, sure I provided update in OP. thank you!

Comment: @TarJae error still occurs when I run knitr

Comment: Please see my update again.

Comment: @Tarjae The problem lies when you knit the markdown. I then receive the same error "## Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
## ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x and y"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72423208/why-does-geom-line-only-work-when-using-group-1-with-it @TarJae

Answer (score 0):

**Update2 for Rmarkdown:**

````
---
title: "test"
author: "TarJae"
date: "27 5 2022"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```


```{r myplot}
axisorder <- c("7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "9:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 AM", "1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM")

hourlyIntensities_data <-  structure(list(Id = c("user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
                      "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
                      "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
                      "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6"), 
               ActivityHour = c("12:00 AM", "1:00 AM", "2:00 AM", "3:00 AM", 
                                "4:00 AM", "5:00 AM", "6:00 AM", "7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "9:00 AM", 
                                "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", 
                                "3:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM", 
                                "9:00 PM", "10:00 PM", "11:00 PM"), TotalIntensity = c(0L, 
                                                                                       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 13L, 13L, 143L, 20L, 11L, 19L, 
                                                                                       54L, 9L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AverageIntensity = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.466667, 0.216667, 0.216667, 2.383333, 
                                                                                                                                                         0.333333, 0.183333, 0.316667, 0.9, 0.15, 0.316667, 0.4, 0.316667, 
                                                                                                                                                         0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
ggplot(data=hourlyIntensities_data, aes(x = ActivityHour, y = AverageIntensity, group = 1 )) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = axisorder) +
  ggtitle("Average Intensity user_6",
          subtitle = "4-12-2016")
```
````

[image]

**Update1:**

Put the aesthetics in the main call with `ggplot()` and leave `geom_point()` and `geom_line()` aesthetics empty:

```
axisorder <- c("7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "9:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 AM", 
  "1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM", 
  "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM")


library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data=hourlyIntensities_data, aes(x = ActivityHour, y = AverageIntensity, group = 1 )) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = axisorder) +
  ggtitle("Average Intensity user_6",
          subtitle = "4-12-2016")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn your time variable into a date-time variable, instead of a character variable, first:

```r
library(ggplot2)
hourlyIntensities_data <- structure(list(Id = c("user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
                                                "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
                                                "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", 
                                                "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6", "user_6"), 
                                         ActivityHour = c("12:00 AM", "1:00 AM", "2:00 AM", "3:00 AM", 
                                                          "4:00 AM", "5:00 AM", "6:00 AM", "7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "9:00 AM", 
                                                          "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", 
                                                          "3:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM", 
                                                          "9:00 PM", "10:00 PM", "11:00 PM"), TotalIntensity = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 13L, 13L, 143L, 20L, 11L, 19L, 
                                                                                                                 54L, 9L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AverageIntensity = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.466667, 0.216667, 0.216667, 2.383333, 
                                                                                                                                                                                   0.333333, 0.183333, 0.316667, 0.9, 0.15, 0.316667, 0.4, 0.316667, 
                                                                                                                                                                                   0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
hourlyIntensities_data$ActivityHour <- as.POSIXct(hourlyIntensities_data$ActivityHour, 
                                                  format = "%I:%M %p")

ggplot(hourlyIntensities_data) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = ActivityHour, y = AverageIntensity)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = ActivityHour, y = AverageIntensity)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%l:%M %p", limits = c(as.POSIXct("7:00 AM", format = "%I:%M %p"),
                                                        as.POSIXct("8:00 PM", format = "%I:%M %p")),
                   date_breaks = "1 hour") +
  ggtitle("Average Intensity user_6",
          subtitle = "4-12-2016")
#> Warning: Removed 10 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
#> Warning: Removed 10 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Okay cool this is working.. only thing is I would like the graph to appear as the graph I have posted in the picture - with x labels 7a to 8p. How would I adjust this? thank you so much! @lhs

Comment: I have also included axis order @lhs

Comment: Updated the axis limits to be between 7am and 8pm

Answer (score 0):

```
# to avoid "axisorder"    
hourlyIntensities_data$ActivityHour_f <- forcats::fct_inorder(hourlyIntensities_data$ActivityHour, ordered = T)

# setting group=1 inside geom_line()
ggplot(data=hourlyIntensities_data, aes(ActivityHour_f, AverageIntensity)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line(aes(group = 1))
```

[image]